# How to add a column to the primary key of a replicated table in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, replication, composite-primary-key

I need to add an existing column in the table to the table's PK. The table is replicated so I am unable to just add in SSMS. Is there a way to do this? The PK is already a composite of 3 columns and now I need to add a 4th column to the definition.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this cannot be done other than by dropping the entire table from replication, and then re-adding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and here's the script to do it:

```
USE <db name>
GO

exec sp_dropsubscription @publication = N'<publication>', @article = N'<article>', @subscriber = N'<subscriber>', @destination_db = N'<destination db>'
GO

exec sp_droparticle @publication = N'<publication>', @article = N'<article>'
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[<table name>] DROP CONSTRAINT [<constraint name>] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
GO

/****** Object:  Index [<index name>]    Script Date: 6/19/2020 7:44:44 AM ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[<table name>] ADD  CONSTRAINT [<constraint name>] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [COL1] ASC,
    [COL2] ASC,
    [COL3] ASC, 
    [COL4] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [MFDP00_MFDP00FG08]
GO

exec sp_addarticle @publication='<publication>', @article ='<article>', @source_object='<source object>', @schema_option=<schema option>
GO

exec sp_addsubscription @publication='<publication>', @article='<article>', @subscriber='<subscriber>', @destination_db='<destination db>'
GO
```